# Logic help for DotNetZip loop logic

Tags: vb.net, zip, logic, dotnetzip

I have a logic problem, just need more brains working on this.

```
 For Each JobNode In JobNodes
                    Dim Source = JobNode.SelectNodes("Source")
                    For Each item As System.Xml.XmlNode In Source
                        Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo

                        ''''Discerns whether a file or directory

                        If item.InnerText.Contains(".") Then 'is a file

                            If Dir$(item.InnerText) <> vbNullString Then
                                mySize += FileLen(item.InnerText)
                            End If


                            zip.AddFile(item.InnerText, "")


                            Dim numFiles2 = filenames.Count
                            mySize = BytesTO(mySize, convTo.MB)
                            Console.WriteLine("...Added all " & numFiles2 & " files. Total loose file collection size is " & Math.Round(mySize, 2) & " MB")
                            Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf)


                        Else 'is a directory

                            zip.AddDirectory(item.InnerText, GetLastDirName(item.InnerText & " "))
                            Dim dinfo As New DirectoryInfo(item.InnerText)
                            Dim sizeOfDir As Long = DirectorySize(dinfo, True)
                            Dim numFiles As Integer = CountFiles_FolderAndSubFolders(item.InnerText)

                            Console.WriteLine("...Added all " & numFiles & " files. Total directory size is {0:N2} MB", (CDbl(sizeOfDir)) / (1024 * 1024))
                            Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf)
                        End If

                    Next
```

This is part of a backup program I made. This is the part that determines if the object to be added to the zip is a file (first part of the IF statement) or a directory (ELSE part of the IF statement).

My problem is, I am trying to add this code:

```
Dim numFiles2 = filenames.Count
mySize = BytesTO(mySize, convTo.MB)
Console.WriteLine("...Added all " & numFiles2 & " files. Total loose file collection size is " & Math.Round(mySize, 2) & " MB")
Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf)
```

Just after the `zip.AddFile(item.innertext,"")` part. I want to add this so that I can get a console print out of the information.

The problem is, if I just put it directly after the `zip.addfile()`, it outputs the code directly above each time. I only want it to print out that part (directly above) once it has finished adding all of the loose files (or files added using `zip.AddFile()`)

EDIT: adding the for loops at the top for more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a flag and then look for it after the loop completes. It seems as though you are looping through the files instead of calling this recursively. I am guessing you have only one loop right now.

Before Loop iteration:

```
Dim FilesBeingAdded as Boolean = False
Dim numFiles2 as Integer = 0
```

Inside of iteration:

```
If item.InnerText.Contains(".") Then 'is a file
     If FilesBeingAdded = False Then
         FilesBeingAdded = true          
     End If

     If Dir$(item.InnerText) <> vbNullString Then
         mySize += FileLen(item.InnerText)
     End If

     zip.AddFile(item.InnerText, "")
     numFiles2 +=1

 Else 'is a directory
     zip.AddDirectory(item.InnerText, GetLastDirName(item.InnerText & " "))
     Dim dinfo As New DirectoryInfo(item.InnerText)
     Dim sizeOfDir As Long = DirectorySize(dinfo, True)
     Dim numFiles As Integer = CountFiles_FolderAndSubFolders(item.InnerText)

     Console.WriteLine("...Added all " & numFiles & " files. Total directory size is {0:N2} MB", (CDbl(sizeOfDir)) / (1024 * 1024))
     Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf)
End If
```

After Loop Iteration:

```
If FilesBeingAdded = True Then
   mySize = BytesTO(mySize, convTo.MB)
   Console.WriteLine("...Added all " & numFiles2 & " files. Total loose file collection size is " & Math.Round(mySize, 2) & " MB")
   Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf)
   mySize = 0
   numFiles2 = 0
   FilesBeingAdded = False
End If
```

So when it finishes the current iteration it will take the tally of files it added, along with the size and print it to the console. It then zeros the variables so that the next iteration of the inner loop has clean values. I am presuming you run this on more than one directory. By checking `FilesBeingAdded` you can be sure to avoid situations where an ugly zero count output is shown if the directory contained no files.

This solution presumes a lot about how you enter this piece of code. If my presumptions were not correct, please modify the question to enable a better solution.

Comment: One thing that might change this is the fact that I'm  using a For statement. Check the EDIT above

Comment: Actually that is exactly how I thought you might be doing it. You would add the `After loop iteration` section of my answer to the body of the outer loop after the inner loop.

Comment: Got it done. Thanks sir. I never had to do something quite like that but it makes total sense.

Comment: Nesting loops is fun, however if you really wanted to make that bugger work for you, you would change it to a recursive function that only handled files. It would be an interesting mental work out if nothing else.